# How to run yesod hello world app with stack?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I've created a yesod project with following command:

```
stack new yeplay yesodweb/simple
```

and I've added a `helloworld.hs` file to app directory. The app directory contains the following files:

```
~/haskell/yeplay/app$ ls
devel.hs  DevelMain.hs  helloworld.hs  main.hs
```

The `helloworld.hs` file  has the following content:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
import           Yesod

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Hello World!|]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 HelloWorld
```

Then I tried to run the file with the command:

```
runhaskell helloworld.hs

Command 'runhaskell' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install ghc
```

as described in the documentation.

How can I start the app?

Comment: http://seanhess.github.io/2015/08/04/practical-haskell-getting-started.html

Comment: Have you tried it, as I described it above?

Comment: `runhaskell` isn't the same as `stack`. Try running `stack build` (could take a while) and then do `stack exec -- runhaskell helloworld.hs`.

Comment: @zero_coding Do you want me to post it as an answer?

Comment: @bradrn  Could explain me, what is the meaning of the `runhaskell` the parameter?

Comment: (Also @zero_coding, you can mention someone using @ followed by their username, otherwise they don't get notified of the message)

Comment: @zero_coding `stack exec -- command` runs `command` in `stack`'s context, which includes Haskell libraries, commands etc. So we're just running `runhaskell helloworld.hs`, but using `stack`. For this sort of thing, I wouldn't use `runhaskell` though; I would use `stack exec yeplay` (the `--` isn't required when the `command` doesn't have any parameters), or `stack exec -- yesod devel` (requires running `stack build yesod-bin` first). Refer to the [Yesod Getting Started page](https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) for more details.

Comment: I am following the instruction on page https://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics and it says to start with `runhaskell`.

Comment: Where are the commands list?

Comment: @zero_coding looks like you didn't read far enough, since the next sentence on that link is: "Note, if you followed the quick start guide and installed yesod with stack then you will not have `runhaskell` and will need to run `stack runghc helloworld.hs` instead. "

Comment: @RobinZigmond Au sorry my mistake. Thanks a lot for the hint.